# How to insert and load TFileStream with TmongoWire

Tags: delphi, mongodb

I use Delphi and TmongoWire. I would like to insert `TFileStream (picture, pdf)` with TmongoWire on a MongoDb server. My work is based on this demo file: [Delphi MongoDB driver](https://github.com/stijnsanders/TMongoWire)

```
 d:=BSON([
  'id',mongoObjectID,
  'name',ItemForm.txtName.Text,
  'address',ItemForm.txtAddress.Text,
  'phone',ItemForm.txtPhone.Text,
  'picture', TFileStream.Create('C:\temp\mongotest.jpeg', fmOpenRead or fmShareDenyWrite)
]);
FMongoWire.Insert(mwx1Collection,d);
//LoadItems;
LoadItem(ListView1.Items.Add,d);
UpdateCount;}
```

Inserting a stream file does not work, can somebody see why ?

The program does not compile : Error --> BSON can not be called with these arguments

There is no problem to insert a simple text field (code below) :

```
    d:=BSON([
  'id',mongoObjectID,
  'name',ItemForm.txtName.Text,
  'address',ItemForm.txtAddress.Text,
  'phone',ItemForm.txtPhone.Text
  ]);
```

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. What does "it does not work" mean exactly? What part "does not work"? Do you get an exception? (Also, your code has an extra `}` that would prevent it from compiling, even if we had the rest of the information.) If you'd like us to help you solve a problem, please be specific about the problem. We can't see your screen or read your mind from where we are, so the only information we have is what you tell us.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and provide that information there, where it can be properly formatted (and easily seen when people read your question). Thanks. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer to this tutorial: http://owlyci.com/docs/articles/WorkingWithGridFS

In GridFS files are referenced by names (or _id in rare cases), so you should save streams to GridFS with some filenames (aaa.jpg, 81276482634823.dat or any other), and then store this filenames to your collection

```
d:=BSON([
  'id',mongoObjectID,
  'name',ItemForm.txtName.Text,
  'address',ItemForm.txtAddress.Text,
  'phone',ItemForm.txtPhone.Text,
  'picture', 'aaa.jpg'
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB has it's own sub-system specifically to store (large) files: GridFS

see more here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/gridfs/

and for a TMongoStream object that uses this: https://github.com/stijnsanders/TMongoWire/blob/master/mongoStream.pas

(For the sake of completeness: Delphi doesn't know by itself how to convert a TFileStream to a Variant, which causes the error.)